# Devise migration not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rake

I created a User model using `Devise` and whenever I use `rake db:migrate` I get the following issue:

```
==  DeviseCreateUsers: migrating ==============================================
-- create_table(:users)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `database_authenticatable' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition:0x00000103fa1ff0>

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I run the full trace with the `--trace function` but can't seem to figure out what the issue is. 
Here is the migration file:

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
def self.up
create_table(:users) do |t|
  t.database_authenticatable :null => false
  t.recoverable
  t.rememberable
  t.trackable
  t.confirmable

  # t.encryptable
  # t.lockable :lock_strategy => :failed_attempts, :unlock_strategy => :both
  # t.token_authenticatable


  t.timestamps
 end

add_index :users, :email,                :unique => true
add_index :users, :reset_password_token, :unique => true
add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   :unique => true
# add_index :users, :unlock_token,         :unique => true
# add_index :users, :authentication_token, :unique => true
end

def self.down
  drop_table :users
  end
end
```

Comment: Can we make the assumption that you have previously run `rails g devise:install` and have a devise.rb in /config/initializers?

Comment: yes I have run rails generate devise:install

Comment: verify that you have "gem 'devise'" in your gemfile, run bundle/bundle install and restart your webbrick. Basically, for one reason or another, devise is not loading in your environment. Its hard to stab our at all the possible reason in this format, so I suggest you just go back and make sure you didn't skip a step when tying in devise.

Comment: I ran through the steps again and it worked this time. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good to hear.
I guess the official answer would be to rerun the steps:

`rails g devise:install`

`rails g devise user`

`rake db:migrate`

`rails s`  // cycle your server just in case...

Answer (score 23):

Devise 2.0 eliminated helper functions for creating the database tables:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Upgrade-to-Devise-2.0-migration-schema-style

So what you need is:

```
create_table(TABLE_NAME) do |t|
  ## Database authenticatable

  t.string :email,              :null => false, :default => ""
  t.string :encrypted_password, :null => false, :default => ""

  ## Recoverable
  t.string   :reset_password_token
  t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

  ## Rememberable
  t.datetime :remember_created_at

  ## Trackable
  t.integer  :sign_in_count, :default => 0
  t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
  t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
  t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
  t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

  t.timestamps

end
```